# No Cache - HTML5 - Resource fetch failed (4)

Tags: html, caching

i want to have absolute no cache in browser(chrome) for my site. i want to solve this with a manifest file, because metatags show no effect.

here my solution:

in html:

```
<html manifest="cache.manifest">
```

in my cache.manifest file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

#Cache manifest version 1.0

CACHE

#no cache

NETWORK
*
```

and the error in the chrome log:

```
Creating Application Cache with manifest http://localhost/editor-xampp/cache.manifest
Application Cache Checking event
Application Cache Downloading event
Application Cache Progress event (0 of 3) http://localhost/editor-xampp/CACHE
Application Cache Error event: Resource fetch failed (4) http://localhost/editor-xampp/CACHE
```

did anybody have a solution for this?
and what means:  `Resource fetch failed (4)`?

thx for ur help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CACHE and NETWORK line was assumed as paths to the resources to be cached.
You need to add a colon ':' after CACHE and NETWORK to indicate that they are sections.

Answer (score 0):

The error event fires when:

> 1) Manifest is not Available

The manifest returns a 410 or 404 HTTP, the attempt to contact the manifest is terminated.

> 2) Referencing Page Failed to Download

The page attempting to contact the manifest experiences a transmission error.

> 3) Fatal Error While Downloading Manifest Contents

A file listed in the manifest encounters an error while downloading.

> 4) Manifest Changes During Update

The manifest changes during an update process (in this case the manifest is contacted again to attempt another update).